# Custom admin page - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

I'm creating an admin (Wordpress) custom page to put there few information: tutorials, links, etc. But can I make it default page? I mean starting page after login? My function below:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_testpage' );

function register_testpage() {
    add_dashboard_page( 'Hello bro!', 'Welcome', 'manage_options', 'backend',     'testpage', plugins_url( 'testpage/images/icon.png' ), 6 ); 
}


function testpage() {
    echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="icon-tools" class="icon1"></div>';
    echo '<h2>Hello!</h2>';
    echo 'Info here...';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: why don't you use some filter and customize the existing dashboard page only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* Redirect the user logging in to a custom admin page. */



    function new_dashboard_home($username, $user){
        if(array_key_exists('administrator', $user->caps)){
            wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=c2c-overview', 'http'), 301);
            exit;
      }}
add_action('wp_login', 'new_dashboard_home', 10, 2);
```